# Get TextBox values entered before postback

Tags: postback

I use the code below to add a dynamic amount of textboxes to a div but I can't get to them before dissappaering at postback. I'd like to be able to loop them to get the values but no matter how I try I can't get the boxes since they all disappear as I click the button to do so. How do I go about to do this?

```
    foreach (string month in budget.PeriodMonths)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
        TableCell tc2 = new TableCell();

        tc1.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;

        Label monthName = new Label();
        monthName.Text = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(month);

        tc1.Controls.Add(monthName);

        TextBox monthInput = new TextBox();
        monthInput.ID = "month_" + i.ToString();
        monthInput.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return isNumberKey(event)");
        monthInput.Width = 50;
        monthInput.Style.Add("TEXT-ALIGN", "RIGHT");

        if (i < sellerBudget.PeriodValues.Length)
            monthInput.Text = sellerBudget.PeriodValues[i].ToString();
        else
            monthInput.Text = "0";

        tc2.Controls.Add(monthInput);

        tr.Cells.Add(tc1);
        tr.Cells.Add(tc2);
        bpTable.Controls.Add(tr);

        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking to get them in javascript or server-side (ASP.NET)?

Comment: I'd hope to do it server side.

Comment: Can you enumerate the controls in the postback? i.e. Page.Controls

Comment: No, I've tried that using this code.             TextBox objBox2;
            objBox2 = this.Page.FindControl("month_1") as TextBox;
            if (objBox2 != null)
                Response.Write(objBox2.Text);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one helped me out enormously! http://techbrij.com/197/retrieve-value-of-dynamic-controls-in-asp-net